# Grails how to write a RESTful post call for my grails application

Tags: rest, grails, post, restful-url, httpbuilder

I am new in writing RESTful calls, and I am also new in Grails. However I am trying to write my first Rest API in my Grails application.

Based on this link:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.10/guide/webServices.html#versioningResources

I noticed that there is fully explanation of how to make a get and post request.

However, I would like to make a rest post call through my code, and not via culr Unix tool.

What should I use? 
I am running Grails 3.0.10, can I use HttpBuilder?

Can you provide me examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research Grails Rest Builder, which is part of the Grails REST API. For example:

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
// POST request and get response back
def resp = new RestBuilder().post("$baseUrl/api/employees/count")
// confirm that status and returned values are ok
resp.status == OK.value()
resp.json.count == 100
```

The groovydocs are here: http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/rest-client/api/index.html. Older documentation is here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/.